# Python Flask app on AWS EC2

Tags: python, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask

I have a Python Flask app structured as from home/Application/demo directory

- src > controller > ( views.py, templates > index.html )
- views.wsgi

**views.wsgi**

```
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, 'Applications/demo/src/controller')

    from views import app as application
```

**views.py**

```
    from flask import Flask

    app = Flask(__name__)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Inside /etc/apache2/sites-available , I created a conf file named mysite.conf with content -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         WSGIDaemonProcess views
     WSGIScriptAlias / /Applications/demo/views.wsgi

     <Directory /Applications/demo/src/controller>
            WSGIProcessGroup views
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And ran these commands -

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo a2ensite mysite.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

When I restart apache and go to the page, I get

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
 <Directory /Applications/demo>
    WSGIProcessGroup views
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

That is, the directory where the WSGI script file referred to by `WSGIScriptAlias` is, not where the modules that then imports are.

Comment: Thank you @Graham but still the same problem. Do I need to give some permission to the file?

Comment: The directories down to all your files and the files themselves must be readable by user that Apache runs as.